# Asp.net mvc entity framework 4.1 saving on sub model codefirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

ok i have model

```
    public long prop1 { get; set; }   

    [Required] 
    public string prop2 { get; set; }

    [Required]    
    public string prop3 { get; set; }      

    [Required]  
    public string prop4 { get; set; }
```

this table is the part of database generated from code first.

now the requirement arises that there will be a form with prop3 only and after submitting it it will be updated on the bases of prop1. how will i make it work with regard to creation of model and dbcontext? what is the usual practise here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking here.  However, if what you mean is that you need to be able to insert an entity with only a prop3, then you have to change your data model to make prop2 and prop4 not be required.

Comment: the thing is that there is already an entry form with prop2 , prop3 , prop4 . now there is a second entry form with only prop3 . and i am using code first approach. hope it is more clear.

Comment: the thing is using the above model will be a problem because it already has required attribute in it.

Comment: @mazharkaunainbaig - a different view model won't help you if your data model has those fields be required.  When you submit your model, it will generate an exception.  This is why you should use view models seperate from your data models.  Your data model has to support all your scenarios.